# c # error al llamar a una clase Thread desde mi clase principal

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos

> El hilo consiste en mover el gif

```
    private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nuevo == true)//si es la priemra vez que has pulsado el boton
        {

            //pedir datos del personaje
            hilo_motor_GIF hilo = new hilo_motor_GIF(muñecoWalker,2);
            hilo.arrancar();
            nuevo = false;
            btn_start.Text = "Seguir aventura";
        }

        else {
            //accionar el personaje

            //accion();
            hilo_motor_GIF hilo = new hilo_motor_GIF(muñecoWalker, 2);
            hilo.arrancar();
        }
    }
```

**clase hilo**

```
    using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public class hilo_motor_GIF
{
    Thread hilo;
    int segundos;
    PictureBox gif;

    public hilo_motor_GIF(PictureBox gif, int segundos)
    {

        this.segundos = segundos;
        this.gif = gif;

        hilo = new Thread(go);
    }

    private  void giffOn() {
        this.gif.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void giffOff() {
        this.gif.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void go() {

        try
        {
            giffOn();
            Thread.Sleep(segundos * 1000);
            giffOff();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: "+e);
        }



    }

    public void arrancar() {
        this.hilo.Start();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> Excepción producida: 'System.InvalidOperationException' en System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'muñecoWalker' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.
>      en System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
>      en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
>      en System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
>      en System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
>      en hilo_motor_GIF.giffOn() en H:\PROYECTOS C#\CaminanteRandom\CaminanteRandom\hilo_motor_GIF.cs:línea 21
>      en hilo_motor_GIF.go() en H:\PROYECTOS C#\CaminanteRandom\CaminanteRandom\hilo_motor_GIF.cs:línea 32
>   El subproceso 0x1154 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
>   El programa '[1232] CaminanteRandom.exe' terminó con código 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 4):

Para modificarlos desde un hilo diferente necesitas utilizar Invoke. Invoke ejecuta el metodo pasado como delegate en el mismo hilo del control.

Ejemplo:

```
private  void giffOn() {
{
    this.gif.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { this.gif.Enabled = true; });
}
```

Alternativamente puedes usar el componente `BackgroundWorker` que te permite realizar lo mismo de una manera más sencilla.

`BackgroundWorker` incluye el evento `ProgressChanged` que se ejecuta en el hilo del componente por lo que no tienes que utilizar `Invoke` y el metodo `ReportProgress` para llamar al evento.